# No module named whaaaaat ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, module, pip

Hey I installed the `whaaaaat` module with

`pip install whaaaaat`

https://pypi.org/project/whaaaaat/#installation

but when I try to import it into a python script I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whaaaaat'
```

I already googled but I couldn't solve it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This should work. Please show your import statement, and also make sure you are in the same environment where you installed the package.

Comment: I copied the code snippet of the Quickstart point from my link. My file is on the Desktop directory

Comment: You mean your source file? Which python version do you use, and do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes I mean my source file. I execute with python3 but I don't really know what u mean by virtual environment. So I guess I don't use it :D

Comment: So, `pip list` shows you that `whaaaaat` is installed, and starting a python prompt and entering `import whaaaaat` gives you an error?

Comment: Ah, and looks like you are under Linux - if you are using `python3` you may also have to use `pip3` to install it, otherwise it will be installed in Python 2.

Comment: are you using ```python3 filename``` or ```python filename```. This usually happens to me. in this case use ```python filename```

Comment: Ok I guess I found the problem but now there is another bug. I tried to just import whaaaaat and then I got the error that in the __init__.py of whaaaat it could not import Token from prompt_toolkit. So I installed prompt_toolkit but the error is there anyways. But thanks for your help maybe I try to avoid whaaaaat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably has different versions of python installed in your system. as you already said in your comments

> "Yes I mean my source file. I execute with python3"

You need to check that `pip` corresponds to `python` and not `python3`

Try installing `python3-pip`
Then use `pip3 install whaaat`
and use `python3 filename` to excute your file

Comment: Thx for your help :) I tried your tips but already have the problem ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whaaaaat_tut.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whaaaaat
  File "/home/jan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whaaaaat/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.token import Token
ImportError: cannot import name 'Token'
```

Comment: I also installed prompt toolkit with pip and pip3

Comment: ok. I saw your comment after posting mine. Did installing prompt toolkit solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I solved by installing the right prompt toolkit version

`pip install prompt_toolkit==1.0.14`